# CSS Error: Expected ':' but found '/'. Declaration dropped. Line: 0

Tags: html, css, firefox, w3c, w3c-validation

I'm getting this one warning/error in all my CSS files for some reason and I can't quite figure it out. When I run my CSS through the [W3C Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcgtweb2.tech.purdue.edu%2F356%2Fgwindes%2Fproject2%2Fstyle.css) it comes out 100% valid correctly formatted etc. However, when using the web developer toolbar in Firefox I get this warning:

`Warning: Expected ':' but found '/'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: filename.php
Line: 0`

Has anyone else run into this problem? I understand this isn't really a big problem and normal users would never see this but I'm just more curious as to what is causing this.

I searched Google but wasn't able to find anyone else with the same problem so hopefully someone on here can help.

Comment: Possible a comment that wasn't closed properly? Seems you've fixed it because when I click on that link I get no warnings or errors.

Comment: @stealthyninja: The error was never on that link. It was Firefox's error console showing the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at this page:

http://cgtweb2.tech.purdue.edu/356/gwindes/project2/

I get the error you described in Firefox's error console.

The reason for this is not inside the CSS file - it's in how you're *including* the CSS file:

```
<link href="style.css" style="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Can you see it?

It's that `style` attribute :)

It should be like this instead (`style` -> `type`):

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Well I be damned. Nice find! How'd you figure it out or just experience?

Comment: I've not come across this one before either :) I figured this out by copying your HTML code into a local file, and eliminating parts of the code as the cause. Firstly, I removed all JavaScript - no change. Then I removed all CSS - the error was gone. Then, I looked closely at how you were importing the CSS file, and it *jumped out* at me.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is not in your CSS files.  Your error is in your php file(s), and is probably a space at the beginning of filename.php or something related.  Without seeing your PHP it's hard to determine what is causing your error, but could be something related to a rewrite rule, importing of a file, etc..

Answer (score 2):

For me style="height=46px;" gave the error, i corrected it back to style="height:46px;". The warning is related to CSS.